# FileItem inputStream to FileInputStream

Tags: java, ajax

I have a web page with an upload feature which lets you upload a excel file, on hitting upload an Ajax call is fired. From there I get the `FileItem` input stream and using the method `fileItem.getInputStream()`, I have another class with a method which I need to pass the file to, which has a `FileInputStream` parameter. So my question is how do I convert the input stream to a `FileInputStream`?

A detailed solution would be appreciated as I am a junior developer, so I am still learning.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html)

> A FileInputStream obtains input bytes from a file in a file system.

I would suggest two solutions:

1. The proper one is to change the API and to have `InputStream` as a parameter. I don't see a reason why you have `FileInputStream` in your API.
2. If you don't own the API and cannot change it I'm afraid you will need to save the `InputStream` to [temp file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)) and then create `FileInputStream` giving a path to this file (it's a suboptimal solution as you first write the file to disk - risking out of space - and then read it and streaming API is designed for reading / writing data on the fly)

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I do own the API so that has fixed my problem. I do have another leading on problem however, the API I am passing my InputStream returns a string with success or error. If I upload a file which has all the correct requirements it comes back with success, and then if I upload another file which I know will have errors, it returns an error but after that even if I upload a working file it doesn't work anymore I keep getting the error message. It seems like that broken file is stored and used again regardless what file you pass in after that. Any thoughts why that could be?

Comment: I have fixed this issue now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem interface then your class is probably DefaultFileItem which is a subclass of DiskFileItem. So you can cast FileItem to DiskFileItem. then if you look at the [source code of DiskFileItem](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/fileupload/disk/DiskFileItem.html) you'll find that getInputStream() is actually returning a FileInputStream or a ByteArrayInputStream If you get a FileInputStream from DiskFileItem you can pass it directly to your other class. But if you get a ByteArrayInputStream you will have to write the contents to your own temporary file and then open another FileInputStream on this temp file. There is also another method DiskFileItem.getStoreLocation() which seem to return the server side File used for upload, but it may return null if the file is cached in memory.

In conclusion: you cannot be sure that there is going to be a server side file because the upload may be cached in memory. Therefore if you need a FileInputStream elsewhere you will have to create it yourself by creating a temp file. There is an example on how to pipe between two streams [here](https://github.com/sergiomt/knowgate9/blob/master/knowgate-base/src/main/java/com/knowgate/io/StreamPipe.java).

Answer (score 0):

//Pass file path/name directly to FileInputStream

```
FileInputStream input1 = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
```

//Save file path that has been passed in by the user, into a string variable.

```
String fileName = args[0];
```

//pass path to File object

```
File inputFile = new File(fileName);
```

//pass file object to FileOutputStream

```
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(inputFile);
```